# Order of the lines in Java manifest files

Tags: java, manifest

Does the order of lines in manifest file matter?

Somebody is trying to convince me that things break for him when the manifest file changes from

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Class-Path: xxx.jar 
Main-Class: com.something
```

to

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Main-Class: com.something
Class-Path: xxx.jar
```

(Main-Class and Class-Path lines are reversed.)

Comment: Make sure there is a line-ending after your last line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the order of those two lines should not matter.

Here's a quote from [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Manifest%20Specification):

> ...
>
> - Versions:
>
>   Manifest-Version and Signature-Version must be first, and in exactly that case (so that they can be recognized easily as magic strings). Other than that, the order of attributes within a main section is not significant.
> - Ordering:
>
>   The order of individual manifest entries is not significant.
>
> ...

Internally the manifest is represented by a `HashMap` which is an unordered data structure. Here's the source code `java.util.jar.Manifest` if you wish to have a closer look.

- http://www.massapi.com/source/jdk1.6.0_17/src/java/util/jar/Manifest.java.html

Comment: Thank you, that settles it. I have found a [link to more recent specs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Notes%20on%20Manifest%20and%20Signature%20Files) but it says the same as yours.