# jar throwing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jar

I've got a project that is structured liked so:

```
root/
-- lib/
---- commons-cli-1.2.jar
-- src/
---- my/package/name/*.java
-- bin/
---- my/package/name/*.class
-- .classpath
-- .project
-- manifest.mf
```

The `*.class` files in `bin/` are made by Eclipse each build. My `.classpath` has the `lib/` included and compiles just fine; it also runs as a "Java Application" just fine with my current stubs.

The issue comes about when I try to create a JAR and include the `lib/` dependencies. From the command line I've been issuing:

`jar cvfm prog.jar manifest.mf -C bin/ .`

The program builds, and then when I try to run `java -jar prog.jar`, I get:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/Option...` (there is more, but I cant copy from the other machine)

My `manifest.mf` looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: my.package.Main
Class-Path: ./lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
```

Seems to me that the `Class-Path` isn't being included and the JAR cannot find the classes contained in the `commons-cli-1.2.jar`. I've isolated this to JAR creation, since I can run the compiled classes with no issue.

What am I doing wrong when creating the JAR and including the `lib/*.jar`?

Comment: this should work I would say. Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: @RC. Think I just figured it out. Apparently `Class-Path` must come BEFORE `Main-Class` in the `manifest.mf`. Where is this doc'd??

Comment: Nope there's no order, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145790/order-of-the-lines-in-java-manifest-files (but maybe the end of line is your issue see the comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had issues with specifying classpath in the manifest file before. If I were you, I would skip referencing the required libraries in the manifest file and instead include them directly inside your jar. Eclipse allows you to easily do this [link](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You probably assume that the build process should pull the commons JAR into the new that holds your classes. Wrong assumption.

The default Java approach is that you only include your classes in your jar. But instruct your users that they need to have the commons jar in their class path as well!

Comment: I'm confused. If I specify the `Class-Path` in the manifest, when the JAR is created, it should pull in the classes from that other JAR shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. This is just meta information that gets added to the jar file. To my knowledge this does not affect the content of the final jar file.

Comment: Sure, but specifying the `Class-Path` should tell the JAR at runtime where to look for external dependencies.

Comment: I would then check if that relative path is really correct in the end. Besides that - is there anything I could do to make my answer at least upvote worthy in your eyes?